# Updating maximum sum subrectangle in a sparse matrix when one element is changed

Tags: algorithm, optimization, matrix, dynamic-programming, kadanes-algorithm

I have an m x n matrix which is sparse with N non-zero entries.
 A modified version of `Kadane's 2-d algorithm` can find the maximum sum subrectangle in `O(m N log n)` time, which beats traditional Kadane's algorithm of `O(m^2 n)` for sufficiently sparse matrices.
 Now I want to know if the optimal solution can be updated quickly if one entry in the matrix is changed.
 By "quickly" I mean something like `O(m log n) time or better`.
 It's possible that perhaps the matrix does not have to be sparse to work out `a solution, however a solution when N = O(min(m,n)) would be ok`.

Comment: This isn't really a programming question... try cs.stackexchange.com instead.